# Intermediate black screen when Navigator.of(context,).pop()

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter app is a mainly a tab app.
In a specific tab "Profile", i have a drawer which show ListTile to "push" another screen in full screen :

```dart
ListTile(
  key: Key("ListTile_EDIT_1"),
  leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
  title: Text('Edit'),
  onTap: () async {
    await Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              fullscreenDialog: true,
              builder: (context) => EditProfilePage(key: Key("EditProfilePage"), user: user)));
                  },
                ),
```

In this screen, i have a Dismissible who pop this screen :

```dart
Dismissible(
 key: Key('Dismissible_Edit'),
 direction: DismissDirection.vertical,
 onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(),
```

The problem is when poping, i have an intermediate black screen, and then the "Profile" show correctly..

Thx,
Nelson

Answer (score 0):

try this

`onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),`

Comment: it was my first test.. still show black srenn. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
await Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(opaque: false, pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => EditProfilePage(key: Key("EditProfilePage"), user: user))
);
```

Comment: i want to po, not adding page to the stack :(. thank you

Comment: but you did want to add new page tho? this is your code right?
`await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      fullscreenDialog: true,
      builder: (context) => EditProfilePage(key: Key("EditProfilePage"), user: user)));
          },
        ),`

Answer (score 0):

replace `onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(),` with `onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.pop(context, true);` or just this `onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.of(context, true).pop(),`

Comment: it was my first test.. still show black srenn. thank you.